# Excel : File Open Dialog in VBA that is set to Detail View and sorted by Date Modified

Tags: windows, excel, vba, dialog

I have tried to Google for this quite extensively but I hope someone here can come up trumps.

As a lot of people ( I imagine ) would like, I want to spawn a File Open dialog box from Excel ( no problem with that using GetOpenFilename ).

I think I am trying to achieve the same thing most people want when they open up a dialog, they want to choose a file, and normally this is the latest one of that type?

So say I have a C:\Temp dir full of .piv files and I want to grab the last created.  I have to open the dialog, change to details and then click the Date Modified column and then this will be the view and set up I want.

I have to do this EVERY TIME, as do the users.  Is there any way of setting the sort and the view type from Excel VBA.

The Chapter 9. stuff from Professional Excel Development gives me some hope, but doesn't get me all the way there.

So strange seeing as it must be a common thing for people to want to do?

Comment: FYI, it is considered polite to upvote the answers you find useful, and perhaps accept an answer that you consider best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my OS and office version (XP with Office 2007) as far as I can tell, it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

There's no official way to do this.  There are hacks but they are very hard to make work across a wide variety of Windows machines.  Getting such hacks to work in VBA sounds exceedingly challenging.

The new file dialogs introduced in Vista remember settings like list view mode, which column was sorted and so on.  I think Microsoft took note of the frustrations people had with the older versions when they designed the new versions.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This is the gist of what I got from my research.  However the stubborness in me means I would like to give it a crack, as we have a very standard build of machine here and would just love to see it working even if it is very fragile, just to se if it can be done.

Comment: Do you know how to write dialog procedures?  I presume your machine is XP?

Comment: I have to admit, I am a little rusty at the native c stuff that I woudl need to write stuff for the dialogs. I am still amazed that for years people all over the world have been putting up with having to repeatedly adjust their view many many times a day. Me included. Why they didn't get a fix for this I don't know!    Yes, I am on a company version of XP still

Comment: they fixed it 4 years ago in vista you are just choosing to run a 10 year old os

Comment: @David: Are you equating "you" = "the company paying your pitance"?

Comment: @Jean It's the plural you, vous rather than tu.

Comment: @Jean I have now just about exhausted my French though!!  ;-)  Pleased you noticed.

Comment: So.. I have Vista at home, what would I be able to do in that case with Excel 2003 or 2007 to achieve my goal?  I plan to blog some sort of solution to this if I can and it seems that from answers below I am in a rut of XP / 2007 which is not possible to deliver anything?

Comment: @ David.  I am not choosing to run a  10 yo OS.  It is the company!  Also I would tend to agree that there is no point in larger companies going to something like Vista with all the cost that is involved and is clearly a flawed OS, so I imagine most companies staying with XP till Windows 7 is working properly and available for corporate builds?

Comment: Vista is not flawed, it's far better than XP. Windows 7 is very mature. Anyway, did Application.FileDialog work out on XP/Office 2007?

Answer (score 2):

Dude, you gotta get with `FileDialog`! This object offers way more flexibility than `GetOpenFilename` (and its sibling `GetSaveAsFilename`).

It will at least get you into Details view automatically. Example:

```
Dim fdgOpen As FileDialog
Set fdgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With fdgOpen
    .Title = "Please open a PIV file..."
    .InitialFileName = "C:\MyDocuments\MyDir\"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails ' Aha!!!
    .Show
End With
```

The above will save you the two clicks required to get to Details view. I don't know whether the last click on "Date modified" can be automated, but hey, at least you're 2/3 of the way.

See [VBA help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa219843%28office.11%29.aspx) on `FileDialog`. It has quite a few useful properties.

Comment: InitialView appears not to have any effect on my Excel 2007. I'd guess from the documentation that this is a component from 2003 days that exposes the Office file dialogs rather than the Windows file dialogs. With Excel 2007 the Office team stopped using their own dialog and used the built in Windows one. I guess that's why initial view is not controllable, but it should at least persist its state. OP will no doubt be on the classic XP/Office 2003 combo.

Comment: Anyway, +1, I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.  However I am on XP / Office 2007 so have had 4 months of fun adjusting to the ribbon and its idiosyncracies.

Answer (score 0):

For XP and Office 2010, `msoFileDialogViewDetails` works.