# How to delete a blank sheet in a workbook using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub delete()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As String, c As Range
    wb = InputBox("work book name")
    Set sh = Workbooks(wb).Sheets
        For Each Sheet In sh
            If IsEmpty(sh.UsedRange) Then
            sh.delete
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

I am unable to delete the empty sheets using above code.

Comment: what do you use the input for? you would need to open a workbook specifying the full path in order to manipulate its data

Comment: If any workbook is having blank sheets,we need to delete them by entering the work book name.

Comment: ok, what about the path to each workbook? where are they located?

Comment: I have no idea about how to enter path.

Comment: Maybe follow [**`this`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500780/excel-file-open-dialog-in-vba-that-is-set-to-detail-view-and-sorted-by-date-mo) to learn :)

Comment: when you are asked to enter the workbook name, enter the full path for example `C:\Users\Sevak\Desktop\SampleFile.xlsm`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below code deletes all empty sheets in the currently opened workbook

try this instead

```
Sub delete()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Sheets
        If IsEmpty(sh.UsedRange) Then sh.delete
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

if you want to specify the full path with the name use

```
Sub delete()
    Dim wb As Workbook, s As String
    s = InputBox("Full workbook path & name")

    Dim fileExists As Boolean
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fileExists = fso.fileExists(s)

    If fileExist Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(s)
        For Each Sheet In sh
            If IsEmpty(sh.UsedRange) Then
            sh.delete
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "File doesn't exist", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: A Workbook must contain at least one sheet or you will get a COMException on the last one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/799908/2258