# Saving a file as a date

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, filenames

I am importing daily data and manipulating it. I want to save the file as the date of the data which is picked up from A4.

The data initially comes in to me as a CSV file and the data is of the format 27/06/2020. I've reformatted the data during the manipulation, but regardless of this, when I come to save the file I get a

> Runtime error 1004 Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
> "C:\Users\steve\Desktop\27\06\D2D75130"

I'm unclear about whether or not (and how) to change this to text format so that it saves - but I like the idea of the date staying in date format to help with my data analysis. Or maybe I should add a text string in front of the date, i.e., "Sales(then the date)" - if that would work? Here is my existing code:

```
' This is to save the file on the desktop using the date (content of cell A4) as the filename
' It also saves the file with the name 'Latest Report' in the Reports Folder


Sub FileNameAsCellContent()

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Path As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Path = "C:\Users\steve\Desktop\" 'change this if you want to save it somewhere else
    FileName = Sheets("Summary").range("A4").Value & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    ' Change the format here which matches with the extention above. Choose from the following link
    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    ' This saves it in the reports folder as 'Latest Report'

    ChDir "C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Reports"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
    "C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Reports\Latest Report.xlsm", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, It should have read as follows: Runtime error 1004 Microsoft Excel cannot access the file "C:\Users\steve\Desktop\27\06\D2D75130"

Comment: Sheets("Summary").range("A4").Value is 27/06/2020

Comment: msgbox displays filename as 27/06/2020.xlsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  `Sheets("Summary").range("A4").Value` has a `/` character in it, you need to replace or get rid of that first, because that character cannot be used in a filename. Use the following line instead to remove that character.

```
FileName = Replace(Sheets("Summary").range("A4").Value, "/", "") & ".xlsm"
```

You could also replace it with a new valid character:

```
FileName = Replace(Sheets("Summary").range("A4").Value, "/", "-") & ".xlsm"
```

[Replace function VBA Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function)

Here's a list of all the illegal characters:

[image]

[Remove illegal characters while saving workbook Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846340/remove-illegal-characters-while-saving-workbook-excel-vba)

Comment: A more comprehensible answer could include (or reference) all the illegal characters (for file names).