# Cannot save a file in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file containing info about 10-11 sessions. I want to create separate excel files for different sessions with format "ProgramNo. ProgramName - Date". Now, I have got the names from the sheet, but am unable to create and save an excel file with that name.

```
For Each b In list3
    Set n = X.Sheets("2023 Feedback Master").Range("A1:A" & CStr(lastRow)).Find(What:=b, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    name = CStr(X.Sheets("2023 Feedback Master").Range("A" & CStr(n.Row)).Value) & ". " & CStr(X.Sheets("2023 Feedback Master").Range("B" & CStr(n.Row)).Value) & " - " & CStr(X.Sheets("2023 Feedback Master").Range("E" & CStr(n.Row)).Value)
    MsgBox folderName & name
    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=folderName & name & ".xlsx"
Next b
```

In the MsgBox foldername & name, I am getting the proper name format. But when using it in the next line, it gives an error

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like `name` contains characters that are not allowed in a filename. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50848245/8422953

Comment: The slash character is not allowed as filename.

Comment: Try using `Replace(everything you placed in name, "/", ".")` to accommodate what brax and FunThomas said (or only on the last part where the date comes from). I'm also not sure why you convert the n.Row to a string there, the date also doesn't need to be converted to string iirc.

Comment: @braX it is working, but the any / or \ gets removed from the filename. The filename comes out to be "CUsersrichakrDocumentswork202337. TA - Self Awareness is the new superpower - 4272023.xlsx" 
I want it to be C\Users\richakr\Documents\work\2023\37. TA - Self Awareness is the new superpower - 4/27/2023.xlsx

Comment: What you want is not possible. You cannot use a slash in the name. You need to replace them with something else (like a dash or a period) in your code as shown above.

Comment: You need to remove and /  and \ from the file**name** (which you call `Name`), but only `/` from the file**path** which you call `folderName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already written in the comments, there are some characters that are not allowed as file/folder name, among them the slash `/`. All you have to do is format the date in a different way. Assuming that column E contains real dates, best is to use the [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)-function.

The following example will write the date in the form yyyy-mm-dd (eg 2023-05-08). I have chosen to use that because writing the date in that order help to sort file names, but you can use any other format you like - just avoid the slash (or any other forbidden character, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50848245/7599798.

Don't remove the backslashes from your save path, and be sure that either `FolderName` contains a trailing backslash or that you add it between `FolderName` and `Name` in the `SaveAs`-command.

Have a look to the following snippet, it also makes your code more readable. I have added a `With`-statement so that you don't have to repeat the sheetname over and over again, and I have removed all the `CStr`-calls: If you use `&` for string concatenation in VBA, there will be an implicit conversion anyhow.

```
With x.Sheets("2023 Feedback Master")
    For Each b In list3
        Set n = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=b, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Name = .Cells(n.row, "A") _
             & ". " & .Cells(n.row, "B").Value _
             & " - " & Format(.Cells(n.row, "E").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")

        MsgBox FolderName & Name
        Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=FolderName & Name & ".xlsx"
    Next b
End With
```