# Download attachment and rename with subject line

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, email-attachments

I am using Office 365.

This code works.

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Users\ppp\Desktop\Image Test"
    
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "" & objAtt.DisplayName
    Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

I want to amend it to save pdf attachments with the subject of the email.

The file is saved as type: file (not PDF) and size is 0 KB.
Additionally it saves the file with the name of the attachment not the subject.

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Users\ppp\Desktop\Image Test"
MSN = Trim(itm.Subject)

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "" & itm.Subject & ".PDF"
    Set objAtt = Nothing
Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: You might be missing a slash here: `objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & itm.Subject & ".PDF"`

Comment: Note that the subject may contain characters which aren't valid in a filename. See here https://www.slipstick.com/developer/saving-messages-to-the-hard-drive-using-vba/#:~:text=Function%20StripIllegalChar(StrInput) for suggestion on "cleaning" the subject

Comment: Also note you're potentially trying to save multiple attachments with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use unique names for files saved to the disk. In the following code the subject property is used for all attachments:

```
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
  objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "" & itm.Subject & ".PDF"
  Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
```

So, you need to add a unique ID to the file name to be able to have them all on the disk. Otherwise, the same file with the `Subject` name will be overwritten.

Second, make sure that file name passed to the `SaveAsFile` method doesn't contain forbidden symbols. See [Remove illegal characters while saving workbook Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846340/remove-illegal-characters-while-saving-workbook-excel-vba) for more information.

Third, make sure that you pass a valid file path to the `SaveAsFile` method. I'd recommend adding the `Debug.Print` statement which could help to identify possible issues with a file path. Just try to print the result file path string to the console and see whether it was built correctly or not.